# dhtmlx scheduler: Prevent an event from being dropped in a particular cell

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

How to prevent an event from being dropped in a particular cell of DHTMLX scheduler?

In other words, How to remove droppable area in a cell?.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement by onBeforeEventChanged event and prevent drop according your requirements
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onbeforeeventchanged_event.html

Comment: I  want to validate before drop, This event called when event is dropped

Comment: this event allows canceling dnd, which looks like exactly what you need - capture onBeforeEventChanged, validate droppable area (start/end date and/or section) and revert dnd if validation fails

Comment: I wanted to validate when dragging over the cell